# Best localization algorithms available in ROS2/ROS1

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, ros2, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used slam_toolbox and AMCL are these the only options.
If we only have slam_toolbox and AMCL then which one is preferred strictly for localization(no mapping ) for large warehouses with a dynamic environment.

Thanks for your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386399/best-localization-algorithms-available-in-ros2/ros1./) by [root-robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/73210/root-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2021-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So you say you aren’t looking for mapping,
but remember that when you say “localize” you had have to localize yourself w.r.t something, a reference. I would guess what you mean is, you just want an odometry estimation, meaning that you want to recieve your localization information w.r.t your initial pose ? Is this what you mean ?
If so, you are not limited to use laser scanner/lidar based slam methods. You can also use a camera based visual slam method such as RTABMap, OpenVSLAM or ORB-SLAM. I have used AMCL but haven’t used the other one, and as far as I remember you had need to provide a prebuilt map, and guessed initial pose to AMCL to start localization. In addition to both those methods there is google cartographer slam package,

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2021-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1